# nodejs - Sending back a stream from a worker thread to the main thread

Tags: node.js, multithreading

I had been trying to separate some work that's done in my program in a different thread.
One of the functions needs to return a stream to the main thread but I'm having the following exception:

```
Error
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> ([worker eval]:12:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
From previous event:
    at PoolWorker.work (node_modules/node-worker-threads-pool/src/pool-worker.js:22:12)
    at DynamicPool.runTask (node_modules/node-worker-threads-pool/src/pool.js:110:47)
    at DynamicPool.exec (node_modules/node-worker-threads-pool/src/dynamic-pool.js:51:17)
    at renderToPdf (src/modules/templates/render2.js:27:14)
    at Context.<anonymous> (test/modules/templates/render.test.js:185:68)
```

I tried to construct a minimal example to reproduce what I'm trying to achieve. Basically, what I need is to send back a readable stream to the main thread. In this example, I'm also having a exception:

To have a pool of worker threads I'm using the library [node-worker-threads-pool](https://github.com/SUCHMOKUO/node-worker-threads-pool#readme) the DynamicPool specifically. And inside I'm trying to convert `html` to a PDF. But I need to somehow return the stream to the main thread.

```js
const os = require('os');
const { DynamicPool } = require('node-worker-threads-pool');

const Pool = new DynamicPool(os.cpus().length);

async function convertToPDF(html) {
  return await Pool.exec({
    task: function() {
      const Promise = require('bluebird');
      const pdf = require('html-pdf');

      const { html } = this.workerData;

      const htmlToPdf = (html, renderOptions) => {
        const options = {
          format: 'Letter',
        };
        return pdf.create(html, Object.assign(options, renderOptions || {}));
      };

      return Promise.fromNode((cb) => htmlToPdf(html, {}).toStream(cb));
    },
    workerData: {
      html,
    },
  });
}

convertToPDF('<div>Hello World!</div>')
  .then((resp) => console.log('resp', resp))
  .catch((err) => console.error('err', err));
```

```
err DataCloneError: function() {
    if (this.autoClose) {
      this.destroy();
    }
  } could not be cloned.
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> ([worker eval]:12:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Do you have an idea of how can I achieve this?

PS: I'm aware that the IO operations are not as performant in the worker threads are they are in the nodejs main thread, but I need to do this to avoid locking the main thread with these operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short version: you can't.

IPC in node is handled through some *black box*, but what we know is that *message objects* are serialized before sending and deserialized once received: you can't serialize a `Stream` because it is based on underling level (a socket, a file descriptor, custom read and write functions, etc) which can't be serialized/deserialized.

So you are forced to exchange serializable data.

Taking a look at `html-pdf` I think an easy way to convert your program is to use `pdf.toBuffer`: rather than trying to send a `Stream` to main thread and reading it in main thread to obtain a `Buffer`, you should send a `Buffer` to main thread and than use it as is.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to give the `Stream` to the main thread, why not just pipe it?

Create a `MessageChannel` shared between them.
The parent implements `Readable`, wrapping its `MessagePort` listening to `.on('message')`.
The thread has an interface that implements `Writable` and basically passes any data from `write()` straight to `.postMessage()`.

<sub>dont forget to add a little more implementation around `write()` for its return value. I'd always return false in the child thread's `Writable`, and forward all `'drain'` events from the main thread's `Readable` back down to the child using `postMessage()` (and force/fudge one when the main thread's *piped*-Writable returned true from our Readable there)</sub>

Now you have a way to *stream* to the main thread.
With the original `Stream` you wanted to send from the child thread, just `.pipe()` it to your `Writable`.
In the main thread simply read from your `Readable` or pipe it on as if you had it for real.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar requirement. I've built a threadpool that sends data back and forth between threads using shared memory. The next step is to add streams. There are two reasons for this: 1) handle data of any size (vs statically allocated buffer) and 2) cut down on memory utilization (i.e. a static buffer of max chunk size that is used serially). The following repo is close to what I need, but I have to go in both directions and control when threads are created/destroyed, etc. https://github.com/pinojs/thread-stream. I think your requirement is to go in the reverse direction also. Nevertheless, this may help with finding a solution.